# Use Powershell while loop to push multiple filenames into a python script

Tags: python, powershell, while-loop

Hi I have a python script.
The script pulls files from a storage account and uploads them to a network drive.

Normally, we get a request for two or three files.
The python script is ran on Powershell.

Here is the command line executed to run the script:

But I want to know a way of running a while loop:

```
python .\download_files.py -f "file1" "file2" -t "459324" -e Dev -id 0
```

where f is filename, t is ticket number, e is environment and id is an ID

If I wanted to while loop the parameter -f, how would I go about that?
Basically rather than having the files added to the script, I am thinking that I create a .txt file with all the filenames and the while loop runs through each one of them.

Comment: Where do you get ticket number, environment and id? Is it fixed or depends on file? If latter, how?

Comment: Why do you need a while loop? In the example you've posted it looks like the python script happily accepts multiple file paths as arguments to `-f`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - the only issue is if I had to provide 100 of filenames.
That would be painful to do in the command line above. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic the environment and id depends on the file. The file sits on sql server (of a particular env) with an assigned id.
The ticket number is a manual addition. So when we run the script, it copies the file to a network drive, and uses the ticket number to name the folder where the files are sitting.

Comment: @JonH Not at all, you can use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to pass a list of arguments: `$files = @('file1', 'file2','file3', ...); python .\download_files.py -f @files ...`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

1. storing the filenames in a file, one filename per line,
2. parsing the content of the file into an array, and
3. passing the array to the python script

does the trick? Something like:

**files.txt**

```
filename1
filename2
filename3
```

**command-line**

```
$files = Get-Content -Path .\files.txt; python .\download_files.py -f $files -t "459324" -e Dev -id 0
```